# BGE Parent actuator not working as expected with multiple objects

Tags: game-engine, parent

I'm trying to make a object rotate around either of two empties, swapping between them when a key is pressed. Logic bricks are as pictured:
[image: player object logic][image: left empty logic][image: right empty logic]
The plan is when a key is pressed the current parent empty and the player object are parented to the other empty and rotate around it. It works the first time around (switch from right empty to left empty). After the second time the right empty does not move with the other objects, but rotates fine.

.blend included [image]

Comment: This sounds like a looping reference. I'm not sure. May I suggest a different solution: Parent the character to one empty. Play an action with positional keys at the left and right foot (action actuator in property mode). This way you do not need to fiddle with dynamic parenting.

Comment: Your suggestion kind of works, the empty moves as the property is toggled, but the player object moves too due to the parenting. Can't replace the parenting with a Child Of constraint as it doesn't work in BGE.